# Chart.js - Connect two datasets in a line chart at same y value

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

### JSBin

Here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/buhupozeka/edit?js,output) of what I currently have.

### Design

Here's a screenshot of a design I'm trying to achieve:

[image: split chart]

### Attempted Solution

I thought by offset them at 0, then meeting at the same value for each dataset, like:

**Data 1**

```
data : [0,randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),20]
```

**Data 2**

```
data : [0,0,0,0,0,20, randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
```

### Issue

would work, but it causes this issue:

[image]

### Relevant HTML/CSS/JS

JSBin may be more current

**CSS**

```
.canvas-container {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height: 500px;
}

#canvas {
  position:relative;
  height: 500px;
  width:100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
var lineChartData = {
  labels : ["","DAY 1", "DAY 2", "DAY 3", "DAY 4", "DAY 5", "DAY 6", "DAY 7", "DAY 8", "DAY 9", "DAY 10" ],
  datasets : [
    {
      label: "Filters",
      fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
      strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
      pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      data : [0,randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),20]
    },
    {
      label: "Filters (Goal)",
      fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
      strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
      pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      data : [0,0,0,0,0,20, randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
    },
  ]

}

window.onload = function(){
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
    responsive: true
  });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="canvas-wrap">
  <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. In case anyone comes across this question, the solution was to used `null` instead of `0` in the data array as necessary.

Ex:

**Dataset 1**

```
data : [5,7,8,9,11]
```

**Dataset 2**

```
data : [null, null, null, null, 11, 5, 8, 3]
```

Comment: I've seen solutions when the null is omitted completely like `[, , , ]`. It may also work.